# Is it possible to reverse a forloop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am trying to figure out how to reverse a for loop, it is kinda hard to explain so I will provide an example:

```
var data_base_array = [3, 3, 1, 4, 1];
var points = [];
for (var index = 0; index <= 4; index++){
    points.push(point_xy_cords[data_base_array[index]][index]);
}
```

`data_base_array` contains numbers between 1-5. Another array contains coordinates of points called `point_xy_cords`. I want to know if there are any methods I can use to reverse this forloop. I can't wrap my head around it, so some logical technique would help get me in the right direction.

If the array `points` change for example, I want to change `data_base_array` accordingly. The values of point_xy_cords looks something like this:

```
point_xy_cords[1-5][0-4][0-1]
```

so if `point_xy_cords[1][0]` then it would give result of two values, `(123.12, 242.11)`.

If `point_xy_cords[1][0][0]` then it would give result of `123.12`.

I'm looking for a solution something like this:

```
for (var x = 1; x <= 5; x++){
  for (var y = 0; y <= 4; y++){
    if (points[y][0] == point_xy_cords[x][y][0] && points[y][1] == point_xy_cords[x][y][1]){
      data_base_array[y] = x;
    }
  }
}
```

The above possible solution didn't work. Any direction would be appreciated. Danke.

Comment: you mean, generically, `for (var i = lastIndex; i>= 0; i--) { ... }` - or in your case `for (var index = 4; index >= 0; index--){`

Comment: If you get confused by something like this, one tip is to manually do the process on paper first before you try to code it

Comment: Are you asking how to reverse the *algorithm*, to take the final `points` array as input and produce something like `data_base_array`? As compared to making an individual loop run in reverse in the sense of going from the last element through to the first? If so, it would help if you could [edit] your question to show a sample of what `points` actually looks like after it is populated. You could probably show all of `point_xy_cords`, too, given that it is only 4x4x2.

Comment: To improve @JaromandaX 's comment, you also need to convert the `push` to an `unshift`. So the code is `for (var index = 4; index >= 0; index--){points.unshift(point_xy_cords[data_base_array[index]][index]);}`

Comment: in that case you'd end up with the same result ... iterate forwards with push === iterate backwards with unshift ... I think :p ... using the "reversed" for loop **or** unshift only would reverse the result with respect to the original array (I may be misinterpreting the question though)

Comment: Yes, I thought that he just wanted to invert the traverse order, maybe you are right :/

Comment: Rather than show us the algorithm why not describe the data structure and how you want it to change? The initial value of `points` is `[point_xy_cords[3][0],point_xy_cords[3][1],point_xy_cords[1][2],point_xy_cords[4][3],point_xy_cords[1][4]]`. OK, I get that. So where do you want to go from here?

Comment: Wait a sec, I think he wants to reconstruct the `data_base_array` based on the `points` array and the `point_xy_cords` array.

Comment: @GramThanos Yes, I think reconstruct is the word I was looking for rather than reverse. After the value of points has changed, I would like to reconstruct `data_base_array` based on points and `point_xy_cords`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you almost got it...

So the relation between your 2 arrays is :

```
                       i1  i2, ...
data_base_array     [  j1, j2, ... ]

                       i1                    , i2                    , ...
points              [  point_xy_cords[j1][i1], point_xy_cords[j2][i2], ... ]
```

So `iX` is the index and `jX` is the value on the `data_base_array` array (where `X` is a number). Also `iX` is the index and `point_xy_cords[jX][iX]` is the value on the `points` array. So the index of the arrays `data_base_array` and `points` is the same (`iX`).

In order to reconstruct he `data_base_array` array, if we know the `points` and the `point_xy_cords` arrays, we need to know the `jX`, but we don't. So we need to search all the possible `jX` to find a possible match on the `points[iX] == point_xy_cords[jX][iX]`.

The reconstruction can be done with the code :

```
// Init array
var data_base_array = [];

// For each `iX` (from 0 to 4)
for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++){

    // Init to an invalid number
    data_base_array[i] = 0; // Zero is invalid

    // Find correct `jX` (so search from 1 to 5)
    for (var j = 1; j <= 5; j++){
        // Check if `points[iX] == point_xy_cords[jX][iX]`
        if (
            // Javascript can't compare arrays, so compare each array item
            points[i][0] == point_xy_cords[j][i][0] &&
            points[i][1] == point_xy_cords[j][i][1]
        ){
            // We found a possible `jX`
            data_base_array[i] = j;
            // Stop search
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

But this is 100% correct, only if you are sure that the pairs in the `point_xy_cords[i][j]` are unique on each column.

Comment: This seems to work but it only decreases the `data_base_array` value correctly but doesn't increase them (results don't show). I'm trying to figure out why, maybe I can work it out. So for example, if value of `data_base_array[0]` is 3, then according to changes in `points`, the loop does change the value to 2 and 1, but doesn't seem to change it 4 and 5.

Comment: If I remove `break;` then it does the opposite. this time it increases but doesn't decrease. Ummm...

Comment: In order for this to work, you need to be sure that each `point_xy_cords[i1][j]` is not the same with an other `point_xy_cords[i2][j]`

Comment: No two points are the same, because they all have different x and y. x or y can be the same, but both can never be the same. That's why && is used. I will probably figure it out after a break. I will comment the answer when I do and choose your answer as correct. Thanks for the direction.